# Logistics model on variable with values 1, 2, 3?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, conditional-probability

I have a dataset containing traffic crash information. One variable in the set is the number of fatalities that resulted in the crash, which has the values 0, 1, 2, and 3.

I am working in R and want to create a logistic regression model to predict the probability that fatalities >= 1. In order words, what is the likelihood that a traffic incident will result in at least one fatality? How would I do this? I am thinking I need to create a new binary variable such that fatalities=yes (1) and fatalities=no (0), but I'm wondering if there's a more simple way. Not that creating the binary variable would be difficult, I guess I'm just wondering if the predictor variable has to be binary, or if it is possible to just set a condition on it (i.e. fatalities>=1)?

Comment: This seems like mostly a programming question, and should go on Stack Overflow. But in R you can do it in the formula directly by using the `I()` function.  `mod <- glm(I(fatalities >= 1) ~ x1 + x2, ...)`. Or you could create a new variable using `>=` and refer to that instead, as you describe. Both should be equivalent

Comment: Yould look into ordinal logistic regression, search this site.

Comment: Thank you, David! That worked beautifully. And I appreciate the feedback. This was my first question to this site, but I will be sure to use Stack Overflow for programming questions in the future.

Answer (score -3):

You could try that binary transformation, directly or as suggested by @david. However, data transformation could change the odds.

For example, if you have $n_{f_0} = 25$, $n_{f_1} = 25$, $n_{f_2} = 25$, $n_{f_3}=25$, now you'll have $n_{f_0}=25$ and $n_{f_1new}=75$. So, the odds are likely to change too much.

Perhaps, you should try first to run the model with $f_0$ and $f_1$ (the original) and then extend the model the $f_{1new}$. And observe the difference.

If results don't seem reasonable (extreme odds), then the easy way is not feasible. Thus you might need to look to ordinal logit, as suggested by @kjetil, which can give you estimated probabilities such as $P[f>1]$.

Comment: How would the odds change?  What odds? From what to what?

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the feedback. Let's give a chance @ Amyxdomz to ask some questions around it.

Comment: We don't work like that.  When multiple interpretations of a question are likely, the risk is that it will collect conflicting answers.  When an answer is confusing, ambiguous, or wrong, it is best that it be either improved or deleted.  For a back-and-forth dialog, please use comments or our chat.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm trying to help @Amyxdomz. If I'm stepping on your territory or have a issue with me, please restraint yourself for such comments. I believe, you can always edit the question and answers. Thank you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "territory" or feelings and everything to do with what this site is for and how it works.  It's ridiculous to request that others do your editing for you.  Please read our [help] for more.

Comment: As for the words you use and the fixation you seem to have, I believe it's getting personal. That is ridiculous, among other things and of course, not professional. Please, stop. If you're the owner and don't want me to play here, please say it so, on chat. Stop harassing me. I don't need to be here, alright?

Comment: I am *moderating,* not harassing.  If you object to moderation, this is not the site for you, because *everybody* (with a sufficient reputation) is a moderator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136215/discussion-between-lima-institute-of-econometrics-and-whuber).

Comment: Whuber is correct. The purpose of comments is to clarify the material in questions and answers. It's very hard to see how this exchange, which asks a clarifying question about the answer, and then explains how this site works, could possibly be harassment, bigotry or abuse.

Comment: Hello @Sycorax. Nice to meet you. Please read carefully this follow-up comment and other comments, and perhaps the pattern of behaviour will be clearer. This is not an isolated incident. Everything started with repeatedly unfriendly and unkind comments from @ whuber, I'm just defending myself. Besides, we're discussing between ourselves (which I call to continue on chat or DM) and the most interested person is absent (@ Amyxdomz) . He's more important than our discussion. In that sense, do you still agree with everything on whuber side?

Comment: I’ve reviewed every reply you’ve received. Nothing seems out of the ordinary: you’ve received feedback about your answers. The purpose of comments is to clarify the content of the answer. If you’re not open to receiving feedback when your answers are unclear or ambiguous, you are not going to enjoy using this website. Please review the [help] for more information about how the site works, because it will be hard for your to understand the goals of the site & how to use it without reading it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Sycorax. Indeed, I'm new on the site. That's why I was expecting more help, rather than "unfriendly or unkind comments" which are well regulated in the code of conduct. Again, I was just defending myself. As interpretation is subjective and the case is likely to continue, I'll collect more evidence, and when advised, I'll file a formal report / legal claim in the future.

Comment: Again, nothing you've experienced rises to the level of "unfriendly or unkind" as described in the code of conduct. Again, the purpose of comments is to clarify the material in questions and answers. You've written a number of short, ambiguous answers; pointing that out is part and parcel of how this site works. Before you spend any time or money finding an attorney to pursue a legal claim, I strongly suggest that you take the time to familiarize yourself with how this site works. If you don't like getting feedback on a website, you really won't like getting laughed out of a courtroom.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I actually used what David had previously suggested and that worked well. However, I will look into ordinal logit as well.